# Thermoelectric Cooler sensor

Tags: power-supply, sensor, fan, peltier, rpm

My team and I are testing our [Peltier Thermo-Electric Cooler Module+Heatsink Assembly - 12V 5A from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1335). We are using an external power source and sensors to get readings for the current, voltage, and temperature. The problem we are facing is that the sensors are reading the fan RPM and not the frequency for the power. We cannot disconnect it as this causes a huge temperature difference in the module. Any advice? This may be sensor or code related.

Comment: What is "the frequency for the power"?  Isn't the power source DC?  Also, please detail each sensor.

Comment: Please post links to datasheets for your components.  A schematic showing how everything is hooked up and even posting your code will help get you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the power to only the peltier, do one of these things:

- Put the fan on a seperate supply
- Get 2 mulitmeters (one for voltage and one for current) and connect them to the peltier (current in series and the voltage across the peltier)
- If your fixing the voltage to the fan and peltier the fan will be a fixed load and will not vary, if you can measure the current to only the fan, it can be subtracted from the value on the power supply to find the peltier current (assuming that the fan and peltier are in parallel with the supply, don't run them in series).